# Uncategorised Error with Xcode 4.2.1

Tags: ios4

I've been building an iPhone app, (now) targeting OS5 for several months & yesterday upgraded to Xcode 4.2.1.

After several builds today I've now hit the following error:

> error:
>   /Users/mike_lynch/Documents/SimpleBookKeeping1/../../Library/Application
>   Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/5.0/Applications/2F75719F-99D8-432C-9F50-E3FD316FCD97/BK
>   Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK
>   Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK
>   Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK
>   Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK
>   Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK
>   Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK
>   Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK
>   Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK
>   Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK
>   Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK
>   Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK
>   Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK
>   Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK
>   Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK Lite.app/BK
>   Lite.app/BK Lite.app/Mileage.nib' is longer than MAXPATHLEN (1024)

It's like it is appending 'BK Lite.app' to the path every time I build.  There is no nest of 'BK Lite.app' directories in finder.

Any help in resolving this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've now looked at BK Lite.app in XCode and it does indeed contain many nested copies of itself.  Deleting it has allowed me to continue compiling, but any ideas on how it happened & how to prevent it still appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Running Product/Clean seems to resolve this issue.